# Laravel how merge two query results into a single object

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-5, backend

I'm currently stuck on how to merge two query results into a single object .  Below is my code.

**EDITED**

Model methods

```
public static function getTeamStats($competitionId, $teamId) {
    return TeamCompetitionStatistics::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
        ->where('teamid', $teamId)
        ->where('periodNumber', 0)
        ->get();
}

public static function getTeamPosition($competitionId, $teamId){
    return self::where('latest', 1)
        ->where('competitionId',$competitionId)
        ->where('competitorId', $teamId)
        ->get(['position', 'streak'])
        ->map(function($item, $key){
            $item->position = $item->position . date("S", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, $item->position, 0));
            if(strpos($item->streak, '-') !== FALSE) {
                $item->streak = str_replace('-', 'L', $item->streak);
            }
            else {
                $item->streak = 'W'.$item->streak;
            }
            return $item;
        });
}
```

Getting values in controller

```
$teamStanding = Ladder::getTeamPosition($request->competitionId, $request->id);
$teamStatistics = TeamCompetitionStatistics::getTeamStats($request->competitionId, $request->id);

$result = $teamStatistics->merge($teamStanding);
```

Returned result: `[{'teamstanding': 'data'}, {'teamstatictics': 'data'}]`

Expected output: `[{'teamstanding': 'data', 'teamstatictics': 'data'}]`

Comment: You can use like this: `$array = array_merge($teamStanding->toArray(), $teamStatistics->toArray()); 
return Response::json($array);`

Comment: @PenAndPapers check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge

Comment: @PenAndPapers Is it works for you??

Comment: @HirenGohel it still returns two object in an array

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use all() function.

```
$teamStanding = Ladder::getTeamPosition($request->competitionId, $request->id)->get();

$teamStatistics = TeamCompetitionStatistics::getTeamStats($request->competitionId, $request->id)->get();

$merged = $teamStatistics->merge($teamStanding);

$result = $merged->all();

// return [{'teamstanding': 'data', 'teamstatictics': 'data'}]
```

Comment: it still returns two object in an array

Comment: I have edited my code, I think you have to use get() function.

Comment: I've updated my code added methods from my Model, I used your solution but doesnt work

Comment: Can you use merge($query,$query,...) ?if you have say 3-4 to do ?

Answer (score 7):

Try `merge()`

The [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) method merges the given array or collection with the original collection.

```
$first = ModelName::where('<fieldName>','<searchText>')
        ->get();
$second = Album::where('<fieldName>','<searchText>')
    ->get();

$finalResult = $first->merge($second);

$finalResult->each(function($record)
{
    echo $record-><fieldName>.'<br />';
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding my answer as the above solutions didn't quite work for me, both just added two separate objects to one array: `{"Name":"A Name"},{"Surname":"A Surname"}`. I had to collect my array and use first.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge

```
$first  = $modelone->where('Id', '1')->first(['Name']);
$second = $modeltwo->where('Thing', '1')->first(['Surname']);

    $collection = collect($first);
    $merged     = $collection->merge($second);
    $result[]   = $merged->all();
    return $result;
//output: [{"Name":"A Name","Surname":"A Surname"}]
```

Comment: This is the best answer. it solved what  I have been looking for for weeks. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Personally I am not a fan on transforming 2 possible big queries in Collections and merge them, seems like a lot of processing in there.

I normally use union(), maybe this can help others.
[Laravel documentation for unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions)

```
$first = DB::table('users')
        ->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereNull('last_name')
        ->union($first)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Will merge also work with paginate? For example can we do stuffs like $merged->paginate(10) ??

Comment: In my project, I am using Fractal for my transformers and I managed to do it there by adding the items in a Fractal Collection ```$collection = new Collection($items, $transformer, $type);``` and than add it in the IlluminatePaginatorAdapter from Fractal as ```$collection->setPaginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($items));``` If you can do it with Fractal, there needs to be a way throught Laravel also.

Comment: thanks am going to try that. What am trying to achieve is a Facebook type newsfeed where you have multiple models ( posts, videos, status, polls ). Now I want to merge all of them and possibly shuffle them so that each model result is not group. Then finally paginate.

Comment: This is more on personal preference but from my point of view, this sounds quite costly. What I will do is having a type Post (posts in db) that has default columns but can have relations to video entity, pools entity etc and than its mostly going to be just the correct relations such as hasMany etc. So instead of making a huge query and merge all data together, ill just return a standardised transformer of Posts which includes relations based on the foreign keys that are available. In this way, you will not need to merge any query.

Comment: Since am paginating per 10 results, I think I might not have to worry about processing time isn't that so? I am new to eloquent relationships on Laravel and my database already contain user generated content so I can't go with that approach right now. Could you show me a code snippet where you used the paginator adapter?? Thanks a lot