# How to merge two Laravel Query Builder Objects into one Query Builder Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have two `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` or `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` objects, each for the same table/model.

I need to merge these two objects into a single one so that the resultant Builder has all the `wheres, joins, group by's, etc` of both the objects

As an example, suppose

```
$query1 = MyModel::where('column_name', $value);
$query2 = MyModel::where('some_other_column_name', $someOtherValue)->join(...some conditions);
```

I need a resultant query which contains both the where clauses and the join (in this example).

```
$resultantQuery = mergeQueries($query1, $query2);

// Equivalent to
$resultant = MyModel::where('column_name', $value)->where('some_other_column_name', $someOtherValue)->join(...some conditions);
```

The resultant can be either of

1. a new Builder object
2. the `$query1` object itself with `$query` merged into it. (Preferred)

What I **don't** want

- Merging them using union
- Getting the results of each query and then merging them

PS, my true goal is to merge a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object into a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object. I get both of these objects from plugins, so I cannot add all the where's and joins on a single object and don't wish to make the resultant query more complex that it already is

Comment: There's no generic way to do this. Some queries will simply be not mergeable at all and any solution even attempting to solve this will become quite complex very quickly. I think this makes this question too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @apokryfos I totally get your point, but in this case, lets just ignore the semantics. I just need to merge all the where's and joins. If the resultant query ends up not working..... well I'll try to fix that after I get something I can actually work on

Comment: may be this Link can help you  [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535539/laravel-how-merge-two-query-results-into-a-single-object]

Comment: @Dp unfortunately no. In the link, both queries are first executed and their resultant collections are merged. I need to merge the queries themselves without executing them

Comment: From my understanding there is not a way of doing this, each query is "unique"... why do you want to "mix" to separate queries into one ? What are you using that requires to join a query to only run once ?